# What are some famous writing advice such as "How to write novels/plays/screenplay" books published in the 1960's-1980's?

Tags: story, plot-structure

So the background is that I've been doing this mini project trying to track down a plot diagram origin for Antigone which was made in the 20th century and after exhausting JSTOR, NYPL, and my Local Library (who don't have books from this period for this type of book), I'm trying my best to get a list of books that might have been published in the 1960's-1980's which are of the "How do you properly write a screenplay/novel" sort of book.

The diagram looks like this:

[image: Diagram of Antigone, Introduction, Inciting incident, sharp upward movement:Rising Action, climax, halfway down and turn flat line: Denouement]

The thing is that google isn't really helping every time I type it in and it isn't coming up with a list of Writing advice manuals, but more "How do I write a book set in the 1970's" etc type of books.

I'm hoping human memory is better than the internet. I've tracked down the first half of the puzzle:

- Aristotle didn't invent the diagram who described a totally different diagram, though it's often attributed to him.
- The start of the diagramming was likely Freytag.
- The rise of the subplot structure. I found the originator for the shape of the diagram, the popularizer, the person who coined conflict as the center of story, the person who coined inciting incident, the person who brought psychology into characters, the person who created the Three Act structure. The person who put "Denouement" into story vocabulary.
- I'm missing the person who used the diagram I have to describe Antigone and who move Denouement to the end of the story rather than the "downward movement." I know it has to be this time period from the books of the previous people and how it was described to me, thus a combination of the previous.

The previous was excruciatingly difficult since almost no one did attributions, especially college professors in the list. (Ironic, but there you go)

I haven't found who actually invented the diagram, so I'm taking a stab it was likely during this time period. Any books from this time period that you personally know of might help me track down the final person/people would help since I can often triangulate.

Given what I've gathered so far, the likelihood the originator is a white man is very high.

Basically I'm trying to trace the origins of popular writer beliefs so people can examine them and instead of blindly believing them, examine the contexts they were made and see if it still applies to them.

Comment: As cited, on the second bullet point, I know it's not Freytag. The third bullet point goes over the authors I've tried. I'm trying to get a lead on the 1960's-1970's authors so I can correct the wikipedia page on story structure. I've been going over the structuralists. I'll take a name from that time period to triangulate.

It's not Aristotle, it's not Shakespeare. It's not Aelius Donatus. It's not Freytag. I listed all of the authors it wasn't on the Wikipedia story structure list page with references. I have a missing time period. Has to be in there.